# Python pandas and numpy: assign numerical values to new variable based on multiple conditions for existing variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is trivial in Excel, why is this so hard in Python?

The goal is to compute the state variable based on several conditions, including the previous value of the state variable as well.
Value is the known integer, Min(3) and Max(3) are simply the minimum and maximum value of a 3 period rolling window shifted forward by one period. This is how far I got.

```
Index Value Max(3) Min(3) 
0     10    nan    nan    
1     20    nan    nan        
2     15    nan    nan         
3     25    20     10    
4     15    25     15     
5     10    25     15     
6     15    20     10
```

What is the best way to calculate the state variable based on the following conditions:

- a) If Value > Max(3) then 1
- b) If Value < Min(3) then 4
- c) If Value <= Max(3) & Value >= Min (3) & previous State = 1 or 2 then 2
- d) If Value <= Max(3) & Value >= Min (3) & previous State = 4 or 3 then 3

Should look like this in final DataFrame:

```
Index Value Max(3) Min(3) State
0     10    nan    nan    nan
1     20    nan    nan    nan    
2     15    nan    nan    nan     
3     25    20     10     1
4     15    25     15     2
5     10    25     15     4
6     15    20     10     3
```

I have mostly tried this using np.where() funtion but always run into problems once I approach c) and d) conditions.

Comment: Could you please show us your code you have tried so far ?

Comment: `nan` means not a number in excel. In python it would just be `string` until you convert it to `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.loc[df.Value.gt(df['Max(3)']), 'State'] = 1
df.loc[df.Value.lt(df['Min(3)']), 'State'] = 4
df.loc[df.Value.between(df['Min(3)'], df['Max(3)']) & (df.State.shift(1).isin((3, 4))), 'State'] = 3
df.loc[df.Value.between(df['Min(3)'], df['Max(3)']) & (df.State.shift(1).isin((1,2))), 'State'] = 2
```

**output:**
[image]

**Explaination:**
the first statement checks where df.Value is greater than df['Max(3)'] and creates a new column 'State' filled with NaNs, and only 1s on the location of the condition

the seconds line sets 4s where df.Value is smaller than df.['Min(3)']

The last two statements check if df.Value is within Max(3) and Min(3) and compares the df.State last value ([.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)). Note: you can also use [.between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) here instead of [.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) if the numbers are subsequential.

Comment: this almost works for me, but when there are multiple State 2 or 3 I get NaN again just as with my own coding 
e.g.:
State  
1
2
NaN
NaN
4"
should be:
State  
1
2
2
2
4

Comment: oh ok, you can use .ffill (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) for that to forward fill the NaNs with the last value, if I understand your issue correctly. Or bfill if you want to backwards fill

Comment: happy to hear it did!